# Having trouble on mouse over tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dreamweaver

I downloaded a webpage template from the internet because I don't know how to design webpage on photoshop. This was the one I downloaded: http://www.freewebtemplates.com/download/templates/9839
And modified it.
And I have this code for mouse over tabs from dynamic drive. But doesn't seem to be working with the template that I downloaded. Here is my current code:

```
 <script src="mouseovertabs.js" type="text/javascript">



</script>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Designed by Web Page Templates</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="bg1">
    <tr>
        <td class="text1" style="height: 50px;">xd627 information management system</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <div id="mytabsmenu" class="tabsmenuclass">

        <td class="bg5"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 62px; padding-top: 15px;">
            <tr align="center">
                <td><ul><li><a href="index.html" class="link1">Homepage</a></li></td>
                <td><li><a href="RegStuds.php" class="link1">Database</a></li></td>
                <td><li><a href="#" class="link1">About</a></li> </ul></td>
                <a href="submenucontents.htm" style="visibility:hidden">Sub Menu contents</a>
               <div id="mysubmenuarea" class="tabsmenucontentclass">

<!--1st link within submenu container should point to the external submenu contents file-->
<a href="submenucontents.htm" style="visibility:hidden">Sub Menu contents</a>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//mouseovertabsmenu.init("tabs_container_id", "submenu_container_id", "bool_hidecontentsmouseout")
mouseovertabsmenu.init("mytabsmenu", "mysubmenuarea", true)

</script>
                </div>
```

What might be wrong here,its working perfectly with my previous one, but with no layout at all:

```
<script src="mouseovertabs.js" type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Mouseover Tabs Menu- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more
***********************************************/

</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="mytabsmenu" class="tabsmenuclass">
<ul>
<li><a href="" rel="gotsubmenu[selected]">Database Manipulation</a></li>
<li><a href="" rel="gotsubmenu" >Register User</a></li>
<li><a href="loginform2.php" rel="gotsubmenu" >Logout</a></li>
<li><a href=""></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="mysubmenuarea" class="tabsmenucontentclass">

<!--1st link within submenu container should point to the external submenu contents file-->
<a href="submenucontents.htm" style="visibility:hidden">Sub Menu contents</a>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//mouseovertabsmenu.init("tabs_container_id", "submenu_container_id", "bool_hidecontentsmouseout")
mouseovertabsmenu.init("mytabsmenu", "mysubmenuarea", true)

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is it that's wrong?  What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Are you getting any console errors ? Did you also download the .js file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be anything between TR and TD tags, but that's where you have your mytabsmenu div. Move it into a normal area on the page (inside your TD maybe), then try again.